# Re-connecting to a process using Java

Tags: java

I'm attempting to connect to a process I created before my application closed.

So basically my method will be to ensure a few processes are running before my Java APP continues, if the processes are not running the app will create new processes. I just do not want to have these processes running as child processes.

I'm already maintaining the PID of the processes i start in a pids file so I know which process I should attempt to reconnect to upon rebooting my app but I have no clue how to actually go ahead and actually re-attach to an existing Process and listen to the input/output stream.

Right now I'm just holding reference to the Process object created by the ProcessBuilder but I'd like to not rely on child processes as they'll be killed once the JVM exits and want them to remain running.

Comment: it's not possible to attach to the stdin/stdout of non-child process.

Comment: Oh okay. I'll see if i can redesign and try another configuration for managing processes.

Thanks!